# Esri Notebook - Select and append records to table

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-python-api, arcgis-notebook

Using Notebook editor in ArcGIS Online i want to extract from a FC table, those records with a specific data and then insert them into a separate table. I am trying the code below, but getting an "TypeError: 'FeatureSet' object is not subscriptable" error.

```py
from arcgis import features
import pandas as pd
from copy import deepcopy
FC_Item = gis.content.get("a1e115946edf47cb8128b8a6cae4b4ec")
ROAD_Records = FC_Item.layers[0]
Table_Records = FC_Item.tables[0]
Current_Sweep_Records = ROAD_Records.query(where = 'Last_Swept_Date > DATE \'2021-04-19\'')
#print(Current_Sweep_Records)    
features_to_be_added = []

# get a template feature object
template_feature = deepcopy(Current_Sweep_Records[0])

# loop through each row and add to the list of features to be added
for row in new_rows.iterrows():
    new_feature = deepcopy(template_feature)
               
    # assign the updated values       
    new_feature.attributes['Road_Name'] = row[1]['Road_Name']
        
    #add this to the list of features to be updated
    features_to_be_added.append(new_feature)

Table_Records.edit_features(adds = features_to_be_added)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `FeatureSet.features[0]`, not `FeatureSet[0]`. `features` will access the individual Feature objects in the FeatureSet as a list, which you can access using a list index.